# Buscar valor en un array de objetos

Tags: javascript, typescript

Necesito buscar en el siguiente array si el campo IdCheck tiene los valores 7,11,y 13, en caso de que tenga los 3 valores positivo que se ejecute la funcion enviarEmail()

```
const array = [
{
    "IdArchivoCheck": 93,
    "IdArchivo": 118,
    "IdCheck": 1,
    "IdExpediente": 4,
    "Archivo": "Archivo Análisis",
    "NombreArchivo": "2000003598906948.pdf"
},
{
    "IdArchivoCheck": 94,
    "IdArchivo": 119,
    "IdCheck": 5,
    "IdExpediente": 4,
    "Archivo": "Doc. avalúos",
    "NombreArchivo": "2000003568906948.pdf"
},
{
    "IdArchivoCheck": 95,
    "IdArchivo": 120,
    "IdCheck": 11,
    "IdExpediente": 4,
    "Archivo": "Solicitud",
    "NombreArchivo": "2000079598906948.pdf"
}
```

]

Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido, que has intentado? Lo ideal sería que pases código explicando donde te trancaste, así podemos ayudarte.

Comment: acabo de publicar como lo logré resolver, quiza haya una forma mas facil, voy a intentar lo que comenta @VFG

Answer (score 0):

Joel. Puedes resolverlo con el código que propongo, pero la próxima vez, por favor, muéstranos a todos tu intento...

```
const arr = [
    {
        "IdArchivoCheck": 93,
        "IdArchivo": 118,
        "IdCheck": 1,
        "IdExpediente": 4,
        "Archivo": "Archivo Análisis",
        "NombreArchivo": "2000003598906948.pdf"
    },
    {
        "IdArchivoCheck": 94,
        "IdArchivo": 119,
        "IdCheck": 5,
        "IdExpediente": 4,
        "Archivo": "Doc. avalúos",
        "NombreArchivo": "2000003568906948.pdf"
    },
    {
        "IdArchivoCheck": 95,
        "IdArchivo": 120,
        "IdCheck": 11,
        "IdExpediente": 4,
        "Archivo": "Solicitud",
        "NombreArchivo": "2000079598906948.pdf"
    }
],
    buscados = [7,11,13];
var encontrados = 0;

buscados.forEach(function(buscado) {
    if(arr.filter(elemento => elemento.IdCheck==buscado).length > 0) {  
        encontrados++;
    }
});

console.log ("Se han encontrado todos? ",encontrados==buscados.length);
///// O, en tu caso, enviarEmail()
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno al final lo resolví creando un nuevo array con los valores IdChecks del array principal, y luego usando la funcion every de la siguiente manera....

```
let nuevoArray: any = [];

this.array.forEach(object => {
  nuevoArray.push(object.IdCheck)
});

const valoresBuscados = [7, 11, 13];

const existenValores = valoresBuscados.every(value => {
  return nuevoArray.includes(value);
});

if (existenValores){ enviarEmail(); }
```